# Como prevenir que uma propriedade seja removida ou modificada?

Tags: javascript

Tenho um objeto e gostaria de prevenir que determinadas propriedades sejam modificadas e ou removidas. O código abaixo é para ilustrar:

```js
var pessoa = {
  nome: 'Fulano de Tal',
  doc: '999.999.999-99'
};

console.log(pessoa);
pessoa.doc = '111.111.111-11'; // Modifica
console.log(pessoa);
delete pessoa.doc; // Remove
console.log(pessoa);
```

É possível prevenir essas ações ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o método **[Object.freeze()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze)**, que evita que as propriedades do objeto sejam removidas ou modificadas (transforma o objeto em *read-only* -- somente leitura), impedindo também que novas propriedades sejam adicionadas.

Sintaxe: `Object.freeze(pessoa);`

Em *modo estrito* (`"use strict";`) irá retornar erros:

```
var pessoa = {
  nome: 'Fulano de Tal',
  doc: '999.999.999-99'
};

pessoa.doc = '111.111.111-11'; // Modifica
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property

delete pessoa.doc; // Remove
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot delete property

pessoa.idade = '23'; // Adiciona
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot add property idade, object is not extensible
```

Answer (score 1):

Sim, existe uma forma de criar uma variavel imutavel utilizando es5.

```
const object1 = {};

Object.defineProperty(object1, 'property1', {
  value: 42,
  writable: false
});

object1.property1 = 77;
// throws an error in strict mode

console.log(object1.property1);
// expected output: 42
```

Este e o mesmo exemplo que a propria documentacao utiliza em:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty